# "mplayer -vo caca fma.avi" lags, how can i skip frames so it doesn't lag

Tags: sound, video, mplayer

"mplayer -vo caca" looks funny and enjoyably fun to watch in breaks, especially as a screen saver!

Unfortunately it lags, and *(since video/asci is synced to sound,)* sound is fragmented *( "s", pause, "o", pause, pause, "u", "n", pause, "d")*.

What command can i add to

```
mplayer -vo caca fma.avi
```

so that it plays in real time, I don't care *(and am hoping actually)* if frames are skipped, I just want to see funny frames of some funny avis *(of course ideally i would just like to watch an episode without frame skips or lags between frames, and my card is not actually low end, especially for asci decoding, but it is an experimental feature, so cant actually complain)*

How to edit the above command so movie is viewed(and heard) at 1x speed?

Answer (score 0):

The MPlayer docs will usually suggest some combination of the following:

```
Try some of the lavdopts,
    e.g. -vfm ffmpeg -lavdopts lowres=1:fast:skiploopfilter=all.
- Broken file
  - Try various combinations of -nobps -ni -forceidx -mc 0.
- Slow media (NFS/SMB mounts, DVD, VCD etc)
  - Try -cache 8192.
- Are you using -cache to play a non-interleaved AVI file?
  - Try -nocache.
```

And perhaps this will be enough for you? BTW for the ultimate coolness you shoud try *-vo matrixview*  :).